# How to use Draw Circle In Unreal

Tags: c++, math, unreal-engine4

I can draw a circle with something like this.

```
DrawCircle(GetWorld(), GetOwner()->GetActorLocation(),XVector, YVector, DebugLineColor, GetPolarGridElement(i, j, k).X, 100, false, -1.0f, LineDepthInt8, LineThickness);
```

The problem is, I cant seem to rotate it correctly with the `XVector`, and `YVector` values. Here Unreal asks for X Axis vector and Y axis vector. How does this work, whats the math behind it? Say for example I have

```
FRotator DesiredAngle = FRotator(0,90,45);
```

How do I convert this to `XVector` and `YVector` such that my circle is drawn correctly?

Comment: I don't know ue4 but a circle can be defined using one vector in 2D ( the vector is the radius or diameter depending on your conventions) in 3D you will need two vectors since there is an infinity of circles that can be defined with one vec.

Comment: I think a good starting point would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Think of the circle as being drawn on a sheet of paper. The `DrawCircle` is asking for the 3d vectors that correspond to the edges of the sheet such that it can render it correctly in 3D space.

As a simple example, you can try using the following:

```
FVector XVector = DesiredAngle.rotateVector(0,1,0);
FVector YVector = DesiredAngle.rotateVector(0,0,1);
```

I had to look up the axis system of UE4, and I found that for the Y axis is "sideways" and the Z axis is "up", so we rotate these according to `DesiredAngle`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey finally figured this out thanks to the help from others below. To add to the answer from Botje. If I wanted to draw a circle that follows the rotation of a actor. I do this:

```
FRotator DesiredAngleZ = GetOwner()->GetActorRotation();
FVector XVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 1, 0));
FVector YVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 0, 1));
```

In my case though I wanted to follow the rotation of the actor, but offset by 90 degrees. I thought I could do something like this

```
FRotator DesiredAngleZ = GetOwner()->GetActorRotation();

DesiredAngleZ += FRotator(0,0,90);
FVector XVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 1, 0));
FVector YVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 0, 1));
```

This though fails terribly. Why? because you cant rotate a `Rotator` like that. My Solution to the problem was to convert both `FRotator`s to quaternions and then multiply them and then convert back. Final solution looks like this:

```
FQuat tempQuat = GetOwner()->GetActorRotation().Quaternion() * 
FRotator(0, 90, 0).Quaternion();

FRotator DesiredAngleZ = tempQuat.Rotator();
FVector XVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 1, 0));
FVector YVector = DesiredAngleZ.RotateVector(FVector(0, 0, 1));
```